# AUCTeX and tabs

Tags: emacs, indentation, auctex, autoindent

I've been tinkering for hours and I'm becoming desperate.

I want tabs! I like tabs, I see no advantage in using spaces and therefore I ident with tabs (alignment is done with spaces though). But I can't get AUCTeX (or LaTeX-mode for that matter) to use tabs - and it does not seem like anyone else in the world has ever wanted it to.

I'm on Ubuntu so AUCTeX is installed by default, and I guess the relevant parts from my `.emacs` are the following:

```
(setq-default LaTeX-default-offset 8)
(setq-default TeX-newline-function 'newline-and-indent)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t) ; I want tabs. I like tabs
(setq-default standard-indent 8) ; A tab is 8 spaces
(setq-default tab-width 8) ; A tab is still 8 spaces... what's the difference to the above?
```

With these settings, it's still indenting using 2(!!) spaces. Please Help and keep in mind that I just switched from vi, so I might not have a firm grasp on every concept of emacs ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the menu bar, click `LaTeX` -> `Customize AuCTeX` ->  `Browse options`. In there, go to the `TeX Indentation` group node and follow it. Within the group, activate the `Latex Indentation` node to make the options visible. Change the `Latex Indent Level` variable from 2 to 8; set for *current session* (to avoid messing thing up if they don't turn out how you hope, give it a try and let us know how it turned out.